# Replace special character from String

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, special-characters

I have a `String` `str =\'abc\'` which I am printing. Its printing like `\'abc'\` instead of `'abc'`.

I have tried this option: `str.replaceAll("\\", "");` but its giving me **java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1**

Can anyone help resolve this issue.

Comment: Would you mind tagging the language please? Probably Java but let's be certain.

Comment: Yes its java. The thing is, we print the C code expression reading it from java. For e.g. char myChar = 'a', when this expression comes to me(java level) we get myChar = \'a\'. So we need to print the same as "[myChar = 'a']". Now, its printing with special character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you mean :

public class Abc {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    String str ="\'abc\'";

    System.out.println(str);

}
```

}

output : 'abc'

it is coming correct for me.

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) { String str ="\'abc\'"; System.out.println(str.replace("\\","")); }this worked for me... Actually I got confuzed with what will be my input, so the input will be \'abc\' and I can use replace("\\","") and that will solve my problem. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using regex you can do:

```
str = str.replace("\\", "");
```

If you have to use regex then you need to use:

```
str = str.replace("\\\\", "");
```

regex needs double escaping in Java since String and regex engine bot needs escaping.

Comment: String str = "\\'a\\'"; System.out.println("The original String : "+str); str.replace("\\", ""); doesnot print the intended result.

Comment: My test case is:
public class StringTest {
 public static void main(String ...string)
 {
  String str = "\\'a\\'";
  System.out.println("The original String : "+str);
  str = getNewString(str);
 }
 private static String getNewString(String str)
 {
  str.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
  System.out.println("The updated String : "+str);
  return str;
 }
}

Comment: `replaceAll("\\\\")` is not the same thing as `replaceAll("\\")`.

Comment: Anubhava : Its not working for me. Its still giving me output as \'abc\' when I use str.replaceAll("\\\\", "");

Comment: Also feel free to create a code sample on `ideone` for something that doesn't work and I will investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

Your method:

```
private static String getNewString(String str) { 
      str.replaceAll("\\\\", ""); 
      System.out.println("The updated String : "+str); 
      return str; 
}
```

will return the initial string, since string is immutable. str.replaceAll will leave str as it is and it will generate a new string.

Change your test case to this:

```
    public static void main(String ...string) { 
        String str = "\\'a\\'"; 
        System.out.println("The original String : "+str); 
        str = getNewString(str); 
    } 

    private static String getNewString(String str) { 
        String rez = str.replaceAll("\\\\", ""); 
        System.out.println("The updated String : "+rez); 
        return rez; 
    }
```